# The job failed the job was invoked by schedule 1016. The last step to run was step1

Tags: sql-server, ssis

> the job failed the job was invoked by schedule 1016. The last step to run was step1

I got a failed message when I tried to run the job, but when I run using SSIS, the package successfully runs. I have already searched google but I can't find the same error with code 1016. Please help for this issue.

Comment: Seems, 1016 is not an error code, but schedule id. I guess, you can try to check job log to see the actual error message

Comment: where i can find job log? actually i already checked in service integration catalog, but in the report the result is successfully.

Comment: SQL Server Agent->Jobs->right click on your job->View History

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the comments indicate, 1016 is not an error message. Instead, it's the identifier for a schedule. That's why you won't find another question about it.

Let's figure out what the failing job is and what it's expected to do.

Using SSMS, connect to the server in question and run the following query

```
SELECT
    SJ.name AS JobName
,   JS.step_id
,   JS.step_name
,   JS.subsystem
,   JS.command
,   JS.server
,   JS.proxy_id
,   JS.step_uid
,   SP.name AS proxy_name
,   C.credential_id
,   C.name AS credential_name
,   C.credential_identity
FROM
    msdb.dbo.sysjobschedules AS SJS
    INNER JOIN
        msdb.dbo.sysjobs AS SJ
        ON SJ.job_id = SJS.job_id
    INNER JOIN
        msdb.dbo.sysjobsteps AS JS
        ON JS.job_id = SJ.job_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
        msdb.dbo.sysproxies AS SP
        ON SP.proxy_id = JS.proxy_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
        msdb.sys.credentials AS C
        ON C.credential_id = SP.credential_id
    
WHERE
    EXISTS
(
    SELECT
        *
    FROM
        msdb.dbo.sysschedules AS SS
    WHERE
        SS.schedule_id = SJS.schedule_id
        AND SS.schedule_id = 1016
)
ORDER BY 1,2;
```

This query will find all the jobs that are members of the job schedule id 1016. Jobs can share a schedule so if you find more than one job (column 1) listed, then you'll need to look at the job execution to figure out which one failed.

This query is going to expose all the data that supports the job step definition so you'll be looking for all the places where step_id = 1 since your error message indicates `The last step to run was step1`  Unless that's the value of step_name then filter for that.

You indicate the SSIS package runs fine as you so the command column should be patched into your question as that identifies "what" the jobs is doing and can provide a reference point to "you" running the package.

Along with that, proxy_name, credential_name, credential_identity if not null indicate we have credentialed proxies in place which add another layer to identifying where the package might have gone wrong.

If this package executes from the SSISDB, then you'll want to dump the error log into your question as well.

```
-- Find all messages associated to the last failing run
SELECT
    OM.operation_message_id
,   OM.operation_id
,   OM.message_time
,   OM.message_type
,   OM.message_source_type
,   OM.message
FROM
    SSISDB.catalog.operation_messages AS OM
WHERE
    EXISTS    
    (  
        -- Find the last failing operation
        -- lazy assumption that biggest operation
        -- id is last. Could be incorrect if a long
        -- running process fails after a quick process
        -- has also failed
        SELECT 
            MAX(OMI.operation_id)
        FROM
            SSISDB.catalog.operation_messages AS OMI
        WHERE
            OMI.message_type = 120
            AND OM.operation_id = OMI.operation_id
    );
```

You can use the native reports (All Executions) to find the failing execution of your package. That first column, `ID` is the operation_id so you can replace the EXISTS clause with a basic `OM.operation_id = 10`  and if you only want the errors, filter for `AND message_type = 120`